# Not found record in MongDB

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb

I am able to get all records from MongoDB. However, when attempting to get a record by ID, I am getting null as response. I am trying the following:

```
import db from '../db/conn';
import { Collection, WithId, ObjectId } from 'mongodb';
...
const collection: Collection<RequestRecord> = db.collection<RequestRecord>('requests');
...    
const record: WithId<RequestRecord> = await collection.findOne({ _id: { $eq: new ObjectId(id) } });
```

Where RequestRecord has the following definition:

```
export interface RequestRecord {
  _id: ObjectId,
  lateEntry: boolean,
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string,
  purchases: Array<object>,
  additionalComments: string,
  employeeId: number,
  approvals: Array<object>,
  submit: boolean,
  submissionDate: string,
  state: RequestStates
}
```

As mentioned before, I am able to connect to the MongoDB and retrieve all records, but I am not able to retrieve a record by ID. Do you find anything wrong with the above?

I am able to get the record using Mongo DB Compass:
[image]

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you find the document using mongo shell?

Comment: I am able to find the document using Mongo DB Compass.

Comment: Please double check you connected the correct database.